# How can I lazy load or preload large background images on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, lazy-loading

I'm new to javascript.

I am trying to lazy load some large background images on my page so that people will see the "loading" gif when the image is loading. I know how to do this on the HTML image tags but not on CSS background-image.

I looked at a few answers and none seem to be sufficient. Some don't even work when I view the demo/jsfiddle.

Again, all I want to do is have a loading gif behind my CSS specified background-images when they are loading so there will be no gaping black holes that lead my visitors to think the site is broken.

I am using LanguidLoad for my html tag images. So if you guys can get it to work with LanguidLoad, that would be best!

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: have a look at progressive jpg or interlaced gif/png. perhaps a better alternative to a loading gif.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an outer div with a constant "loading" image in the background. Then the lazy-loader class will hold the dimensions that the image will take once it's loaded. When the image loads into it, it'll cover the loading gif image.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-cointainer">
    <div class="lazy-loader">
        <!-- Image will load here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS could look like this:

```
.image-container{
    background-image: url(img/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}
.lazy-loader{
    width: 100px;   //Your image's width
    height: 100px;  //Your image's height
}
```